# Android: How to change the color of a button?

Tags: android, xml

I'm using Eclipse ADT and I need to know how to change the default color of a form widgets button from the default gray to other color, of course using the xml.

Comment: This is a duplicate of *so* many questions.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use 9 patch images.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/patch_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/patch_normal" android:state_enabled="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/patchdisable" android:state_enabled="false"/>
```

[image: Normal]
[image: Pressed]
[image: Disabled]

And in Xml

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_register"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/patch"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="REGISTER"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Using code in you activity class:

```java
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 255));
btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("blue"));
```

---

#### Doing it straight from your XML:

Add this property to your `Button` in your XML file:

```xml
android:background="#800080"
```

`#800080` is purple.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml, you can set the background color by using `android:background="#FF0000"`

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/loadimage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load Image" 
        android:background="#FFFF00"/>
```

you can set any background color of your choice...:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer my friend

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/grey"/>
```